# imacros use datasource loop on mac firefox

Tags: loops, csv, datasource, imacros

When I run my code I get this error... 
(the imacro stops on the datasource line)

[image]

I might not be writing a correct datasource line. (the csv file is in the default path)

I'm trying to import csv data and loop my actions in the process:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE pages.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
'Start at line 1 in the file 
SET !LOOP 1
'Increase the current position in the file with each loop
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
set var1 {{!COL1}}

TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.cnnc.com/{{var1}}
wait seconds=4
TAG POS=7 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:
wait seconds=4
```

I'm trying to repeat the second section of macros continuously. 
Loop with next input from csv file.
Using the free firefox version, if that helps.

Comment: Your macro must work correctly. Probably, there may be a problem with the CSV structure, for example some unsupported characters. First of all remove `SET !ERRORIGNORE YES` and test only the first part using the command `PROMPT {{!COL1}}` in order to view results.

Comment: nothing seems to pop up. I don't see where any text is supposed to show? ...like is it supposed to show the prompt in a pop up window? @Shugar

Comment: its shows in the url as www.cnnc.com/__undefined__

Comment: If `{{!COL1}}` returns `__undefined__`, this means that by some reasons your macro doesn't read info from the file.  Play the following code which consists of two lines only: `SET !DATASOURCE pages.csv` and `PROMPT {{!COL1}}` . (You may try it both in usual mode and in loop mode.) What result or errors do you get? If you don't know how the prompt-dialog looks like, play this line: `PROMPT "Hello, marriedjane875 !"` . In addition you can indicate the browser and add-on versions you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE pages.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}} 
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
'Start at line 1 in the file 
SET !LOOP 1
'Increase the current position in the file with each loop
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
set var1 {{!COL1}}

TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.cnnc.com/{{var1}}
wait seconds=4
TAG POS=7 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:
wait seconds=4
```

I added SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

Comment: this works. for some reason on my mac it won't work if i copy and past the info into the data source file. only if i write each line individually. wierd, right?

Comment: do you know how to read from multiple datasources in the same macro file?